# Why can't neutral pion decay to two neutrino's

Tags: particle-physics, weak-interaction, pions

I know neutral pions mostly decay electromagnetically to two photons, but I don't understand why the decay to two neutrino's is not possible.

Perhaps they violate parity, but someone at the link https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/is-neutrino-spin-parity-1-2-or-1-2.934771/ said it does not make sense to talk about parity for neutrino's since they are produced only via the weak interaction, which does not conserve parity.

Comment: The answer is clear, thank you. I thought it had to do with the helicities of the neutrino's causing the weak suppression.

Comment: Oh!, that too! You are right. In complete analogy to charged-pion decays, the weakly-interacting neutrino will be left-handed and the antineutrino right-handed, so, there will *also* be a helicity violation proportional to a power of the neutrino masses! The decay is triply doomed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pion decay to two photons is electromagnetic (the original flavor chiral anomaly). But decay to two neutrinos could only go through a box diagram involving *two* Ws of opposite charge: the quarks or antiquarks hairpin of the pion wavefunction has to decay to a virtual $W^+ ~ W^-$ pair, which then connect to a similar hairpin involving a virtual charged lepton and a $\nu ~\bar \nu$ pair of decay product particles.

- That, then,  entails a **doubly weak suppression**, by, at the very least, a factor of $(m_\pi/M_W)^8$ ... twenty two orders of magnitude. Hopeless.

As for parity, indeed, the doubly weak interaction blasts parity to vapor, but further consider that a neutrino-anti neutrino pair has the parity of a quark-antiquark pair…

Comment: Hopeless, but not forbidden, so it's "possible" but super rare.

Comment: Wait until you start studying nucleon decay….

Comment: hahahaha, LOL :)